# How to avoid trading holidays during historical data

Tags: python

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history

def importdata(stock):
    stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
           start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 15),           end=date.today(),
           futures=True,
           expiry_date=date(2022,7,28)) 
                              
    print(stock_fut[["Underlying","Change in OI","Open Interest"]])

a = ["MARUTI","HEROMOTOCO","BAJAJ-AUTO","M&M","EICHERMOT"]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    print(a[i])
    importdata(a[i])
```

Now I want only last 10 days historical data. So I need to change the timedelta value regularly.What will be the code for start date and end date so that it always give me only 10 days data without need of changing timedelta value. In other words it takes input of 10 days always excluding Saturday, Sunday and other trading holidays.

Comment: First of all, the term 'Trading Holidays" will have different meaning depending on the country, and the exchange.  Python's dateutil library has functionality related to implementing trading holidays.  See the docs for more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Now accounts for weekends **and holidays** (using nsepy.live get_holidays_list) in an attempt to "auto-find" start date.  Think this is fetching proper data but doesn't seem very efficient in that it makes separate requests for each symbol... any suggestions out there?

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from nsepy import get_history 
from nsepy.live import get_holidays_list
import pandas as pd 

num_days = 10
dt_today = date.today()
holidays = get_holidays_list(dt_today - timedelta(days=num_days), dt_today)

def get_start_date(days=10):
    sdate = dt_today
    while days > 0:
        if sdate.weekday() not in [5, 6]:   # not a weekend (saturday, sunday)
            if sdate not in holidays.index: # not a holiday
                days -= 1
        sdate = sdate - timedelta(days=1)
    return sdate

dt_start = get_start_date(num_days)

def get_stock_history(symbol):
    return get_history(
            symbol      = symbol,
            start       = dt_start,
            end         = dt_today,
            futures     = True,
            expiry_date = date(2022,7,28))

columns = [ # in df returned by get_history
    'Symbol', 
    # 'Expiry', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Last',
    # 'Settle Price', 'Number of Contracts', 'Turnover', 
    'Open Interest',
    'Change in OI', 
    'Underlying'
    ]

symbols = [ # of stocks to evaluate
    'MARUTI', 
    'HEROMOTOCO', 
    'BAJAJ-AUTO', 
    'M&M', 
    'EICHERMOT',
    ]

print(get_holidays_list(date(2022,1,1), date(2022,12,31)))

for symbol in symbols:
    print(pd.DataFrame(get_stock_history(symbol), columns=columns))
```

Comment: Not helpful for me. Can you place my output into pd DataFrame so that I can use df.head(10) module plz. Since there are total 6 stocks data output, I'm not able to understand which code line should I place into pdDataFrame.

Comment: from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd

def importdata(stock):
   stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
   start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 18),           
   end=date.today(),
   futures=True,
   expiry_date=date(2022,7,28)) 
                              
   #print(stock_fut[["Underlying","Change in OI","Open Interest"]])

a = ["MARUTI","HEROMOTOCO","BAJAJ-AUTO","M&M","EICHERMOT"]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
   #print(a[i])
   importdata(a[i])
    
   A = {importdata(a[i])}
   df = pd.DataFrame(A)
   print(df.head(10))

Comment: I tried this but getting nothing but zero. Plz try to help by this method. Here, I think I'm going wrong regarding index and column name. I want the same headers in pdDataFrame as in my original script output.